# Do I need license to run IBM Websphere MQ Explorer?

Tags: license, websphere

I am using IBM Websphere MQ Explorer and IBM Packaging utility. I assumed they are free to use cause they are readily available for download off of IBM's website and don't have any expiration timer. Now I heard someone saying that I need license to use these tools. Do I need to buy some sort of license to use them ??

Answer (score 2):

You are licensed to used MQ Explorer by the license for your queue manager. MQ Explorer is a tool that is not useful unless you have a queue manager! You can of course download the free trial, in which case you cannot raise problem tickets (PMRs) to get support, but if you have purchased a queue manager then you are licensed.